# Limit users action - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, ibaction

I'm trying to implement a vote feature on my app. I would like the user to only vote once on my app after he presses the button. The user can't press button after it's pressed, however, when cancelled and reloading the app the user can still press button and increase the "count". I tried integrating a disable button function but that still does not limit the user from voting(or pressing the button).

Would I have to create an if method for `saveInBackgroundWithBlock` or is there something else that could prevent the user from the action again?

Here is the code where the action is:

```
    @IBAction func voteButton(sender: UIButton) {
    disableButton(sender)

    let hitPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
    let hitIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(hitPoint)
    let object = objectAtIndexPath(hitIndex)
     self.userVote?.addObject(object!)
    polls.addObject(object!)
    object!.incrementKey("voteUp")
    object!.saveInBackground()

    self.tableView.reloadData()
    NSLog("Top Index Path \(hitIndex?.row)")
}
```

Here is the disable button function:

```
  func disableButton(button: UIButton){
        button.enabled = false
        button.userInteractionEnabled = false
        button.alpha = 0.5
    }
```

Comment: You need some persistent storage to keep track of if the users has "already voted", without seeing your implementation details for the entire project its hard to tell how you need to persist this data.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the button like this:

```
@IBAction func voteButton(sender: UIButton) {
sender.enabled = false
}
```

Comment: could you post your function?

Answer (score 0):

you can save the state of the button by `NSUserDefaults`, I suggest you upload user‘s vote state  to the server. every time you load the viewController, you can load the state from the server.

```
@IBAction func voteButton(sender: UIButton) {

    let hitPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
    let hitIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(hitPoint)
    let object = objectAtIndexPath(hitIndex)
     self.userVote?.addObject(object!)
    polls.addObject(object!)
    object!.incrementKey("voteUp")
    object!.saveInBackground()

    self.tableView.reloadData()
    NSLog("Top Index Path \(hitIndex?.row)")

    //save the statue of button
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(“true", forKey: “buttonState")
}
```

then in the `viewDidLoad()`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    //get the state of the button
    if let _ = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey(“buttonState”) {

    self.yourButton.userInteractionEnabled = false
    self.yourButton.alpha = 0.5

    } 

}
```